# Adobe AIR vs Flash Player - sendtoURL Reliability - Alternatives

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, controls

I'm controlling an Arduino Relay using simple sendtoURL commands. Quite by accident I was testing in the Flash debugger and it worked flawlessly.

Once I realized I was in the wrong environment and I did the same test, I noticed a huge difference in performance.

It's hard to explain so I made a video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=on1tluBtA6s

Is there any way to get the Flash Runtime performance within AIR?

What might be causing this and what could I use as an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Originally using a proxy server, must Flash to communicate with Arduino. Maybe you are also using it the same way right? However, Recently in Adobe AIR using a ArduinoConnector.ane direct you to the Arduino can communicate with. I have tested it using(RFID communicate). The existing proxy server is much faster than going via.

[ArduinoConnector link](https://code.google.com/p/as3-arduino-connector/)